# 'int' object has no attribute 'iloc' Viewing data Python/Pandas error

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to view the imported data through pandas, however when I run the script I am presented with the error "int' object has no attribute 'iloc". I am new here and this is my first post so apologies if I don't know the rules. My code is below.

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot

from pandas import read_csv
filename = '/Users/rahulparmeshwar/Documents/Algo Bots/Data/Live Data/Tester.csv'
data = read_csv(filename)

pd.set_option('display.width',100)
pd.DataFrame.head(1)
print(pd)
```

I am new to Python too.

Comment: Please include the _full_ error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to call `head()` on your dataframe `data`, not on the constructor `pd.DataFrame`.

```
data = read_csv(filename)

pd.set_option('display.width',100)
print(data.head(1))
```